# If $\dim_K F<\infty$, must there exist $t\in F$ such that $K[t]=F$

Tags: field-theory

Let $F$ be a finite dimensional extension field of a field $K$. Must there exist $t\in F$ such that $K[t]=F$?

I think I can prove this when $\operatorname{Char}K=0$, but what about the other cases?

Thank you

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem

Comment: @egreg Thanks, so looks like the idea that I had in mind regarding the Char K=0 case won't work, no ?

Comment: The result is true in characteristic $0$. See http://www.math.cornell.edu/~kbrown/6310/primitive.pdf